# how to invalidate server side caching on apache

Tags: apache, caching, invalidation, mod-expires

I've used apache's content expire times for caching of static assets. The only way I know of to force it to update the content on command is to restart apache. is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching on our server, as it turns out, was data stored in a file, so we had to clear the cache file's contents, and voila, the cache was cleared.